# Ember install:bower vs Bower install

Tags: javascript, ember.js, bower

When you want to install a bower package to your ember project, what is the difference between this command

```
bower install <package>
```

and this one

```
ember install:bower <package>
```

I assume the second one is better (correct me if i'm wrong) but ***why***?

Comment: From ember-cli version 0.2.3, ember install:bower command has been deprecated. Now it supports only "ember install <ember-cli-addon-name>".

Comment: I see. Do you have any idea what the purpose of the command was? @SelvarajMA

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/2800

It is not different from bower install <package>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bower install`, since `ember install:bower` was removed from `ember-cli:0.2.4`.

Commands `ember install:bower` and `ember install:npm`  were introduced in `ember-cli:0.1.5`.

They do the same thing as `bower install` and `npm install` with a few options added and they use the local version rather than the global.

This approach sometimes generate unexpected issues (see https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3140#issuecomment-72037408),

so from `ember-cli:0.2.4` `install` command is used exclusively to install addons `ember install <addon-name>`.